# draw line in place of x axis in view controller

Tags: swift, uiview, constraints, center, layer

I want my swift code to draw a line like the place of a x axis. So the line is in the center of the screen no matter what screen size the object is displayed in. My code below produces a line but it does not account for the device size. My image below displays a black line which is what my current code produces and the orange line is the desired output.

[Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocgOt.png)

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let lineView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: 320, height: 1.0))
        lineView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        lineView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        self.view.addSubview(lineView)
    }


}
```

Comment: Why you don't subclass UIView and override its draw() method to draw your line there, exactly where you want it? UIBezierPath can draw all kinds of shapes - try moveTo() and lineTo() to draw a line, and research UIBezierPath drawing examples. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622529-draw https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/drawing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To draw a line in the middle of the screen, just assign the `Line.swift` file to UIView on which you want to draw a line.

`Line.swift` file

```
class Line:UIView {

var line =  UIBezierPath()

func drawLine() {
    line.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: bounds.height / 2))
    line.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: (bounds.width) , y: bounds.height / 2))
    UIColor.black.setStroke()
    line.lineWidth = 0.1
    line.stroke()

}

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
         drawLine()
       }
    }
```

To assign it to your `UIView`, open the `main.storyboard` and click on the view where you want to draw the line. Then, go into upper right tabs which would look like this

[image]

You can see inside the `class` field, there is a placeholder called "UIView". Type there `Line` and hit enter, and then just run the project. You 'll be able to see the line in the middle of the view. No need to declare or call any function. Just assign this class and run the project.

Comment: How would I call this func in class view controller view did load Line() does not work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to respond with the width of the view, you can use constraints:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let lineView = UIView()
    lineView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    lineView.layer.borderWidth = 1
    lineView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    view.addSubview(lineView)
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        lineView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor),
        lineView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor),
        lineView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 100),
        lineView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1)
    ])
}
```

---

For what it’s worth, rather than drawing lines using the border of a view, I'd define a `UIBezierPath` and use that for a `CAShapeLayer`’s path:

```
@IBDesignable
class GraphView: UIView {
    let shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer = {
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        return shapeLayer
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect = .zero) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.minX, y: 100))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX, y: 100))
        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
    }
}
```

Then you can add this view to your view hierarchy like shown above, or right in Interface Builder (obviously, defining the constraints in IB, too).